# Programs needed for phone application creation with database

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I am new to the world of phone application and needing some guidance and a point in the right direction not looking for a tutorial of such just the programs needed.

Lets say i am trying to create a phone application of a phone book that holds text and images the person would search through the phone application and it would then take that information from a database through the internet connectivity.

Something similar to using xamp and mysql through a web browser - taking data from a database thought a web page.

Hope i explained in enough detail.

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: You could do this either as a responsive website, a cross platform app or native apps (one per platform). Figure out which road you want to take (they all have pros and cons), and start looking into the tools available. There are a lot

Answer (score 1):

There are some neat websites like firebase.com. They store all your data in JSON. You can then create a mobile app using PhoneGap and connect to their api to get your data. You can do some cool stuff with PhoneGap and firebase. Phonegap lets you use HTML,CSS,JS to build a mobile apps.

Comment: I touched into phone-gap with my tiny toe and did not like it but I will look at it again..moved onto android studios now.